# Cannot trigger Gitlab-CI pipeline from SVN > Git translated branch [Subgit]

Tags: svn, gitlab-ci, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner, subgit

We are using Subgit to create a one-way mirror from Subversion > Gitlab. This is working perfectly fine. We also have a few branches in this repository and we are able to manually trigger a gitlab pipeline from any of these branches.

When we create a new branch in Subversion it's translated without problem. However when we try to manually trigger a gitlab pipeline from that newly made branch it doesn't appear in the branch list. If we try it using the Gitlab API we get the following response:
`{"message":{"base":["Reference not found"]}}`

The new branch is a fork of the mainline branch and it contains a .gitlab-ci.yml file. As far a gitlab-ci/the gitlab runner is concerned the branch doesn't exist. However in the repository I can see it and it updates on a new commit just fine. I'm quite lost since as far as I know if there is a branch, gitlab should be able to launch a pipeline from that branch.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. Any ideas on why this is are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a SubGit tool support engineer, I would be glad to help you to resolve that issue, but it looks complex and it needs an investigation to find the cause and a solution. However, we would need to check SubGit logs to find the cause, so I suggest to open a ticket on our support forum support.tmatesoft.com and upload all SubGit logs from the affected repository. Alternatively, you can send an email with logs to support@subgit.com.

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to a permission problem.

If the files that SubGit creates or modifies can't be read by gitaly, you'll run into issues. Make sure you run SubGit as the same user as gitaly (typically 'git'), and fix any permission issues.

Once that's done, run this in the Gitlab rails console:

`project = Project.find(<ID OF PROJECT>)`

`project.repository.branch_names` (your branch should not be visible in the output of this command)

`project.repository.expire_branches_cache`
`project.repository.branch_names` (your branch **should** now be visible in the output of this command)